# How to implement pagination for fastapi with mongo db(Motor)

Tags: mongodb, pagination, pymongo, rest, fastapi

I have a simple REST api which is a books store created with FastAPI and mongo db as the backend (I have used `Motor` as the library instead of `Pymongo`). I have a `GET` endpoint to get all the books in the database which also supports query strings (For example : A user can search for books with a single author or with a genre type etc).

Below are the corresponding codes for this endpoint :
`routers.py`

```
@router.get("/books", response_model=List[models.AllBooksResponse])
async def get_the_list_of_all_books(
    authors: Optional[str] = None,
    genres: Optional[str] = None,
    published_year: Optional[str] = None,
) -> List[Dict[str, Any]]:
    if authors is None and genres is None and published_year is None:
        all_books = [book for book in await mongo.BACKEND.get_all_books()]
    else:
        all_books = [
            book
            for book in await mongo.BACKEND.get_all_books(
                authors=authors.strip('"').split(",") if authors is not None else None,
                genres=genres.strip('"').split(",") if genres is not None else None,
                published_year=datetime.strptime(published_year, "%Y")
                if published_year is not None
                else None,
            )
        ]

    return all_books
```

The corresponding model :

```
class AllBooksResponse(BaseModel):
    name: str
    author: str
    link: Optional[str] = None

    def __init__(self, name, author, **data):
        super().__init__(
            name=name, author=author, link=f"{base_uri()}book/{data['book_id']}"
        )
```

And the backend function for getting the data:

```
class MongoBackend:
    def __init__(self, uri: str) -> None:
        self._client = motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient(uri)

    async def get_all_books(
        self,
        authors: Optional[List[str]] = None,
        genres: Optional[List[str]] = None,
        published_year: Optional[datetime] = None,
    ) -> List[Dict[str, Any]]:
        find_condition = {}
        if authors is not None:
            find_condition["author"] = {"$in": authors}
        if genres is not None:
            find_condition["genres"] = {"$in": genres}
        if published_year is not None:
            find_condition["published_year"] = published_year
        cursor = self._client[DB][BOOKS_COLLECTION].find(find_condition, {"_id": 0})
        return [doc async for doc in cursor]
```

Now i want to implement pagination for this endpoint . Here i have a few questions :

1. Is it good to do pagination on database level or application level ?
2. Do we have some out of the box libraries which can help me do that in fastapi ? I checked the documentation for https://pypi.org/project/fastapi-pagination/ , but this seems to be more targeted towards SQL databases
3. I also checked out this link : https://www.codementor.io/@arpitbhayani/fast-and-efficient-pagination-in-mongodb-9095flbqr which talks about different ways of doing this in Mongo db but i think only the first option(using `limit` and `skip`) would work for me, because i want to also make it work when i am using other filter parameters (for example for author and genre) and there is no way i can know the ObjectId's unless i make the first query to get the data and then i want to do pagination.

But the issue is everywhere i see using `limit` and `skip` is discouraged.

Can someone please let me know what are the best practices here and can something apply to my requirement and use case?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no right or wrong answer to such a question. A lot depends on the technology stack that you use, as well as the context that you have, considering also the future directions of both the software you wrote as well as the software you use (mongo).

Answering your questions:

1. It depends on the load you have to manage and the dev stack you use. Usually it is done at database level, since retrieving the first 110 and dropping the first 100 is quite dumb and resource consuming (the database will do it for you).
2. To me is seems pretty simple on how to do it via `fastapi`: just add to your `get` function the parameters `limit: int = 10` and `skip: int = 0` and use them in the filtering function of your database. `Fastapi` will check the data types for you, while you could check that limit is not negative or above, say, 100.
3. It says that there is no silver bullet and that since `skip` function of mongo does not perform well. Thus he believes that the second option is better, just for performances. If you have billions and billions of documents (e.g. amazon), well, it may be the case to use something different, though by the time your website has grown that much, I guess you'll have the money to pay an entire team of experts to sort things out and possibly develop your own database.

#### TL;DR

Concluding, the `limit` and `skip` approach is the most common one. It is usually done at the database level, in order to reduce the amount of work of the application and bandwidth.

Mongo is not very efficient in skipping and limiting results. If your database has, say a million of documents, then I don't think you'll even notice. You could even use a relational database for such a workload. You can always benchmark the options you have and choose the most appropriate one.

I don't know much about mongo, but I know that generally, indexes can help limiting and skipping records (docs in this case), but I'm not sure if it's the case for mongo as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer !! What I meant was filtering on the basic of ObjectId and not using skip and limit would be difficult because I would like to do pagination on the results of the returned results(like for example : searching for books from a specific author), and unless I get the results I don't know the objectId's in advance.

Comment: I'm not getting it. You want to filter the results, based on the objectid and then do the limit and skip stuff?

Comment: If i could have used the ObjectId for filtering then i don't have to use limit and skip as mentioned in the post https://www.codementor.io/@arpitbhayani/fast-and-efficient-pagination-in-mongodb-9095flbqr . It is possible if i am doing the pagination for all the books in the database. But anyways i liked your answer a lot and solved quite some things.

Comment: It is true that you can use the objectid for pagination, though, what if a user wants to sort books? Or what if there's a new book that you have to add after id X and X+1 is already in use? Relying just on the objectid is not a good idea, in my opinion. Thanks for accepting my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use this package to paginate:
https://pypi.org/project/fastapi-paginate

How to use it:
https://github.com/nazmulnnb/fastapi-paginate/blob/main/examples/pagination_motor.py

Comment: Can we pass an AsyncIOMotorCursor to the paginate function as argument ?

Comment: Obviously not. I'm currently figuring this out. fastapi-paginate package has no useful documentation, unfortunately.